# n goes to $\infty$, then $1/a_n$ equals to 1/A for A $\ne$ 0

Tags: limits

Asume that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n = A$ $,A\ne 0$. How can i prove that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}1/a_n = 1/A$$

Comment: This is kind of ill-posed if $A=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we rewrite the known limit to $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - A = 0$, it becomes quite useful:
$$\frac{1}{A} - \frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{a_n}{A \cdot a_n} - \frac{A}{A \cdot a_n} = \frac{a_n - A}{A \cdot a_n}.$$ Now, $\lim_{n \to \infty} A \cdot a_n = A^2 \neq 0$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - A = 0$, hence
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{A} - \frac{1}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n - A}{A \cdot a_n} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - A}{\lim_{n \to \infty} A \cdot a_n} = \frac{0}{A^2} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Argue that for any continuous function, $f(\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(a_n)$.

From here, you can note that $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on the domain $\mathbb R-\{0\}$.

**Edit** this actually might have been a good argument, but if $a_n=0$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$, we might run into some formal trouble. One would need to first verify that there are only finitely many $n$ for which $a_n=0$. This is no longer the easiest way to answer the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the proofs in this vein proceed in a similar manner (in particular, start with the third paragraph of this answer and proceed from there).

First, observe it doesn't make sense if $A = 0$.

Take any $\delta > 0$ (restricting ourselves to looking at small enough  $\delta < |A|/2$). Then, for $n$ sufficiently large, $|a_n - A| < \delta$, ie $A -\delta < a_n < A + \delta$.

Assuming $A > 0$, we can reciprocate and don't need to invert the inequalities, because we chose $\delta$ small enough to ensure the first and last parts are both positive. (The case $A < 0$ is very similar but requires inverting the inequalities). This gives:

$\frac{1}{A}(1 - \delta/A)^{-1} < \frac{1}{a_n} < \frac{1}{A}(1 + \delta/A)^{-1}$

Can you complete the proof from here by showing that, for a given $\varepsilon$, by choosing $\delta$ sufficiently small, we can achieve $(1 \pm \delta/A)^{-1} < 1 + A \varepsilon$?